# How can I clear a `StringIO` instance?

Tags: ruby, stringio

How can I clear a `StringIO` instance? After I write to and read from a string io, I want to clear it.

```
require "stringio"
io = StringIO.new
io.write("foo")
io.string #=> "foo"
# ... After doing something ...
io.string #=> Expecting ""
```

I tried `flush` and `rewind`, but I still get the same content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`seek` or `rewind` only affect next read/write operations, not the content of the internal storage.

You can use [`StringIO#truncate`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-truncate) like [`File#truncate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-i-truncate):

```
require 'stringio'
io = StringIO.new
io.write("foo")
io.string
# => "foo"
io.truncate(0)   # <---------
io.string
# => ""
```

Alternative:

You can also use [`StringIO#reopen`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-reopen) (NOTE: [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html) does not have `reopen` method):

```
io.reopen("")
io.string
# => ""
```

Comment: It appears that [StringIO#reopen](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-reopen) works as well: `io.string #=> "foo"; io.reopen(''); io.string #=> ""` . Yes?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, Thank you for the comment. I didn't know it. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Please see the answer below by JML. Without the rewind, future writes to the StringIO will begin at the position after the length of the previous value, and the string will be left padded with binary zeros.

Answer (score 4):

I use `truncate` AND `rewind`. The rewind is required to prepare io for next operations.

```
io.truncate(0)
io.rewind
```